# R - replacing blank row values with conditional values from another column

Tags: r

I tried searching and found answers to replacing blank row values with other columns but not on the conditions. Let me explain.

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Name    Grade    Test1    Test2    Test3
John    A        none     none
Jane             B ok     none
David            none     C barely
Sam     B        none
Thomas                             D fail
```

I would like replace the missing grades in the Grade column with only the letter grades (remove the following comments) from the other columns. There will never be multiple letter grades in Test1/Test2/Test3 columns. So the result I'm loolking for is this:

```
Name   Grade    Test1    Test2    Test3
John   A        none     none
Jane   B        B ok     none
David  C        none     C barely
Sam    B        none
Thomas D                          D fail
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you add the output of `dput(data)` to the post so we can easily load the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've shamelessly nicked @akrun's data to show an alternative way of doing it that fits in with the [split-apply-combine](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) paradigm

```
# define data
df1 <-  structure(list(Name = c("John", "Jane", "David", "Sam", "Thomas"
), Grade = c("A", "", "", "B", ""), Test1 = c("none", "B ok", 
"none", "none", ""), Test2 = c("none", "none", "C barely", "", 
""), Test3 = c("", "", "", "", "D fail")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Grade", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -5L))

# load up libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# add a primary key
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(PK = 1:nrow(df1))

# turn the test results into tidy format, first by making long and skinny
# and then by bringing it back to one entry per person who has a test result    
test_result <- df1 %>%
   select(PK, Test1:Test3) %>%
   gather(Variable, Value, -PK) %>%
   mutate(Value = ifelse(Value == "none", "", substring(Value, 1, 1))) %>%
   # drop all the unnecessary rows:
   filter(Value != "")

   # join back to the main data, fill in the test score when needed
df1 %>%
   select(PK, Name, Grade) %>%
   left_join(test_result, by = "PK") %>%
   mutate(
      Source = ifelse(Grade %in% LETTERS, "Grade", as.character(Variable)),
      Grade = ifelse(Grade %in% LETTERS, Grade, Value)) %>%
   select(-Value, - PK, -Variable)
```

This give you a nice tidy dataset that should be better for future analysis and re-use too:

```
    Name Grade Source
1   John     A  Grade
2   Jane     B  Test1
3  David     C  Test2
4    Sam     B  Grade
5 Thomas     D  Test3
```

Comment: thank you for this, I used this method to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the columns are `character` class, we get the index of 'Grade' elements that are blank ('i1')

```
i1 <- df1$Grade==''
```

We loop over the 'Test' columns i.e. columns 3 to 5 using `vapply`, subset the elements in those columns that have a non-space (`\\S`) followed by a space (`\\s`) using `grep`, remove the space and the characters that follow it with `sub` and assign the output to the blank elements in 'Grade'.

```
df1$Grade[i1] <- vapply(df1[i1,3:5], function(x)
    sub('\\s+.*$', '', grep('^\\S\\s', x, value=TRUE)), character(1))
df1
#    Name Grade Test1    Test2  Test3
#1   John     A  none     none       
#2   Jane     B  B ok     none       
#3  David     C  none C barely       
#4    Sam     B  none                
#5 Thomas     D                D fail
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(Name = c("John", "Jane", "David", "Sam", "Thomas"
), Grade = c("A", "", "", "B", ""), Test1 = c("none", "B ok", 
"none", "none", ""), Test2 = c("none", "none", "C barely", "", 
""), Test3 = c("", "", "", "", "D fail")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Grade", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I tried it on your `data`, first take out none from the data frame, then substring for the grade portion of each string, then combine all of the columns into one and generate your final table:

```
data[data=="none"]=""
A=function(x) substring(x,1,1)
data1=data.frame(data[1],apply(data[2:5],2,a))
all.grades=paste(data1$grade,data1$test1,data1$test2,data1$test3,sep="")
data1$grade=all.grades
final.data=data.frame(data1[1:2],data[3:5])
final.data

name   grade   test1    test2    test3
john       A                      
jane       B    B ok                
david      C          C barely       
sam        B                      
thomas     D                    D fail
```